# Cross-referencing between tex-files

Tags: cross-referencing, external-files

I have a main TeX-file named `Thesis.tex` that contains this:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, oneside]{Thesis}
\begin{document}
\input{./Chapters/MethodologyAndResearchStrategy}
\input{./Chapters/CreationOfTheNovelDesignPrinciples}
\end{document}
```

Within the file named `MethodologyAndResearchStrategy.tex` - I have a section that looks like this:

```
\section{Quantitative Data Analysis}
\label{sec:QuanDat}
Quantitative data means data, or evidence, based on numbers.
```

Then I have a reference to it that looks like this within a file named `CreationOfTheNovelDesignPrinciples.tex`:

```
As mentioned in (Section~\ref{sec:QuanDat})
```

This then produces "Section ??", which means that it is not finding the label that I have made. I have already tried adding

```
\usepackage{xr}
\externaldocument{MethodologyAndResearchStrategy}
```

in the chapter that I want the reference in, but to no avail. I get an error saying that one can only use such code in the preamble. Putting it there in the main `Thesis.tex` did not yield any results either for that matter. This is my first post, so if you need any other data to be able to assist, just let me know!

**EDIT:** So I finally found the problem, and it had nothing to do with TeX at all. I had been editing the wrong version of `CreationOfTheNovelDesignPrinciples.tex` which was uploaded to Dropbox with an older version of the paper.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Are those files being included in the same project or two completely independent ones?

Comment: I edited my question, hopefully it will make things more clear.

Comment: Did you run latex multiple times? You do not need `xr` for this.

Comment: I ran it three times, and each time I only got the ??. Then I tried  to add a random label within `CreationOfTheNovelDesignPrinciples.tex` which worked fine.

Comment: Try retyping the ref and label. I get the feeling, that there could be some invisible character involved.

Comment: I tried renaming it and typing everything once more, but still no change. I also tried referencing one of the tables from `MethodologyAndResearchStrategy.tex` and using the `(Section~\ref{sec:QuanDat})` reference right below the actual section, which both somehow worked fine.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem due use of wrong files